# Integrate S3 uploader in Web Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web application and i want to integrate Amazon s3 uploader into my web application admin side.In which i can directly use s3 uploader from my web app instead of using it seperately from browser using plugin. Can anyone please help me how to do this. Any documentation available will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wordpress, there is a very nice plugin you can just install easily in your admin panel:

http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-aws-s3-browser/6470423

Comment: No i am not using wordpress it's a standalone php web app.